# Restore last scene from previous session

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Is there any way to restore the last scene from previous session based on cached path in local storage (eg. redux-persist)?

Currently it has to be done in `ComponentWillUpdate` of the initial scene, which will cause the initial scene to be displayed before it gets transited to the last accessed scene.

It cannot be done in `ComponentWillMount` as the state from local storage only gets hydrated after `ComponentWillMount` has already been executed.